# Filtrar datos por producto en Norwind

Tags: mysql, sql

¿Cómo puedo filtrar el producto que más se vendió en cada año en la base de datos de prueba de Norwind?. Estoy trabajando con MySQL.
El resultado que busco es así

| Año | ProductID | ProductName | CantidadVendida |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1996 | 11 | producto 11 | 500 |
| 1997 | 5 | producto 5 | 602 |
| 1998 | 38 | producto 38 | 904 |

Con la siguiente consulta solo puedo obtener la CantidadVendida pero no el ProductID:

```
SELECT sub.anio, MAX(sub.suma) as MasVendido
FROM 
    (SELECT ord.`ProductID` as producto, YEAR(os.`OrderDate`) as anio, 
    SUM(ord.`Quantity`) as suma
    FROM orderdetails ord
    INNER JOIN orders os on ord.`OrderID`=os.`OrderID`
    GROUP BY producto, anio) as sub
    GROUP BY sub.anio;
```

Porque si añado el campo "producto" a la cláusula GROUP BY de nuevo me tira más de 200 resultados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta hacer una subconsulta para este caso.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de como podrías hacer esto:

```
SELECT anio, producto, suma as CantidadVendida
FROM (
    SELECT ord.`ProductID` as producto, YEAR(os.`OrderDate`) as anio, SUM(ord.`Quantity`) as suma
    FROM orderdetails ord
    INNER JOIN orders os on ord.`OrderID`=os.`OrderID`
    GROUP BY producto, anio
) as sub1
WHERE (anio, suma) IN (
    SELECT anio, MAX(suma)
    FROM (
        SELECT ord.`ProductID` as producto, YEAR(os.`OrderDate`) as anio, SUM(ord.`Quantity`) as suma
        FROM orderdetails ord
        INNER JOIN orders os on ord.`OrderID`=os.`OrderID`
        GROUP BY producto, anio
    ) as sub2
    GROUP BY anio
);
```